# How do I test if a type is within another class exists?

Tags: c++, c++14, template-meta-programming, sfinae, type-traits

I was thinking that I could test (with C++14) if a class contained a type, I could do this:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

struct X {
  using some_type = int;
};
struct Y {};

template <typename T, typename = void>
struct has_some_type : std::false_type {};

template <typename C>
struct has_some_type<C, typename C::some_type> : std::true_type {};

static_assert(has_some_type<X>::value); // unexpectedly fails
static_assert(has_some_type<Y>::value); // correctly fails
```

But the `static_assert` fails, which surprised me, since checking for a member function would work in a similar way.

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

struct X {
  void some_function();
};
struct Y {};

template <typename T, typename = void>
struct has_some_function : std::false_type {};

template <typename C>
struct has_some_function<C, decltype(std::declval<C>().some_function())> : std::true_type {};

static_assert(has_some_function<X>::value); // correctly succeeds
static_assert(has_some_function<Y>::value); // correctly fails
```

Why doesn't this work and how would I test if a class has a type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Why does the `has_some_type` trait fail?

It's because the deduction of the second template argument only uses the primary template, and doesn't "take hints" from your template specialization.

Think of your partial specialization of `has_some_type` when you substitute `X` for `C`:

```
template <>
struct has_some_type<X, int> : std::true_type {};
```

this substitution doesn't fail, but - why would it match `has_some_type<X>`? When the compiler sees `has_some_type<X>`, it will ruthlessly ignore your attempts to catch its attention, and simply use the `= void` for deducing the second template parameter.

#### Why does the `has_some_function` trait succeed?

Look at the second type you use in the specialization:  `decltype(std::declval<C>().some_function())`. What is that type resolve to, for `X`? ... yes, it resolves to `void`. So when you substitute `X` for `C`, it's:

```
template <>
struct has_some_function<X, void> : std::true_type {};
```

and this *will* match `has_some_function<X>`, using the `= void` from the primary template.

#### How can we fix the `has_some_type` trait?

<sub>While C++17 and C++20 offer easier solutions (as suggested by @Frank and @Quimby) - let's stick to C++14 and think about fixing what we've already written.</sub>

From the `has_some_function` example, we might be inspired to "fix" the type trait by replacing the primary template with `template <typename T, typename = int>` ;  but while this would work for `X` and `Y`, it would not work if you had `using some_type = double` or any other non-int type. And that's not what we want :-(

So, can we have a type whose definition is: "check the validity of `some_type`, whatever it may be, but eventually just behave like a single fixed type"?  ... Yes, it turns out that we can.

```
#include <type_traits>

struct X {
  using some_type = int;
};
struct Y {};

template<typename T>
using void_t = void;
    // Please Mr. Compiler, make sure T is a legit type, then use void.

template<typename, typename = void>
struct has_some_type : std::false_type { };
 
template<typename T>
struct has_some_type<T, void_t<typename T::some_type>> : std::true_type { };

static_assert(has_some_type<X>::value, "Unfortunately, X doesn't have some_type");
static_assert(has_some_type<Y>::value, "Unfortunately, Y doesn't have some_type");
```

Only the second assertion fails.

See this in action on [<kbd>GodBolt</kbd>](https://godbolt.org/z/Ke6PdhP7v).

---

Notes:

- This solution is actually valid C++11.
- C++17 introduced [`std::void_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t) to save you some typing. It also supports variadic parameter packs rather than just single types.
- If you use an old compiler, the code above may fail due to [C++ standard defect CWG1558](https://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/issue1558).

Comment: A defect, CWG 1558

Comment: Thx.  Very well explained.

Answer (score 5):

I know the question is tagged C++14, but for the sake of other people landing here:

In C++20 and above, [concepts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) provide a clean syntax (not to mention also remove the need for `static_assert` and `enable_if` in many scenarios) for checking if a type has a given type member:

```
template<typename T>
concept has_some_type = requires {
  typename T::some_type;
};

struct X {
  using some_type = int;
};
struct Y {};

static_assert(has_some_type<X>); 
static_assert(!has_some_type<Y>);
```

Comment: Yeah.  I do like concepts.  Not in the cards atm though.

Answer (score 3):

You are using `void_t` idiom incorrectly. The correct way is:

```cpp
template <typename C>
struct has_some_type<C, std::void_t<typename C::some_type>> : std::true_type {};

static_assert(has_some_type<X>::value); 
static_assert(!has_some_type<Y>::value);
```

For C++14, define `void_t` as:

```
template<typename T> struct void_impl { using type=void;};
template<typename T> using void_t = typename void_impl<T>::type;
```

To recap the idiom:

1. `has_some_type<X>` is completed with the default arguments from the base template to `has_some_type<X,void>`.
2. The compiler tries to find all matching specializations for `has_some_type<X,void>`.
3. - **Original** - `has_some_type<C, typename C::some_type>`  is considered, `C` can be deduced to `X`, `X::some_type` is valid **but is not of type `void`**, so the specialization doesn't match an the primary template is used.
   - **Fixed** - `has_some_type<C, std::void_t<typename C::some_type>>` is considered, C can again be deduced, this time `std::void_t<typename C::some_type>` is valid expression of type `void`. This matches and is considered more specialized than the primary template and thus chosen.

Meaning, you always want the expression inside the argument to evaluate to whatever is the default type. The expression just cleverly contains the syntax you want to test.

Second example:

```
struct has_some_function<C, std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<C>().some_function())>>
```

Cast to void will also work in this case:

```
<C, decltype((void)std::declval<C>().some_function())>
```

Comment: This is a C++17 solution...

Comment: @einpoklum Thanks, I should start reading the tags. Give me a second.

Comment: You also refer to OP's use of `has_f()`, while the failing code is `has_some_type`.

Comment: @einpoklum but `has_f` only works because the function returns `void`, I think that is not what OP meant. It's not `has_f`, more like `has_f_returning_void`.

Comment: I meant, you have your identifiers mixed up. In step 1 you talk about `has_f`, then in the middle of step 2 you switch to `has_some_type`

Comment: @einpoklum Oh, you are right, thanks again :) I just copy pasted the wrong thing.

Comment: @Quimby, Oops.  Yeah.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks all.  I thought that I tried that before and then was trying everything else when it didn't work as expected.  Must have been due to some other reason though.

Comment: Why are you defining `void_t` that way?  Why not just use `template<typename T> using void_t = void;;`?  Is that because void isn't a dependent type and this is another, "no diagnostic required" thing?

Comment: @Adrian Because [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t) warns about a defect in the standard  CWG 1558. But I guess with up-to-date compilers either definition should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use type_traits:

```
#include <experimental/type_traits>

struct X { using some_type = int; };
struct Y {};


template <typename T>
using has_some_type_detector = T::some_type;

static_assert( std::experimental::is_detected_v <has_some_type_detector, X> );
static_assert( !std::experimental::is_detected_v <has_some_type_detector, Y> );
```